# jQuery append() issue

Tags: jquery, append

I have 2 images one as a background image and 1 as a foreground image

the css is as follows :

```
#backImage{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    z-index: 0;
}

#mainImage{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 12px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

The mark-up is as follows :

```
<div id="homepageCarousel">
    <img id="backImage" src="discreet images/white_bg.png" />
        <img id="mainImage" src="discreet images/homepage_img1.jpg" />  
    //some other divs
</div>
```

I have a navigation bar at the top,

as I hover over each item in the bar, the `mainImage` should go and the image corresponding to the navigation item should appear.

How can I do this in jQuery, this is what I have thus far : (for now, I'm just trying to `remove()` and `append()` the `mainImage`)

```
$("#navigation li").mouseover(function(){
        $("#mainImage").remove();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $("#backImage").append("<img id='mainImage' 
           src = 'discreet images/homepage_img1.jpg' />");
});
```

Comment: Can you show a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem and approach? Also, I believe that appending and removing elements is pretty expensive; have you considered just changing the `src` of the image element?

Comment: I'll try getting the live demo ASAP, meanwhile I'll try changing just the `src`. cheers

Comment: @david That worked !!! stupid me, just didn't think of it .. thanks. Post your comment as an answer, shall accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest simply changing the `src` attribute of the `img` element, rather than appending and removing elements as those are expensive operations to run.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing `#mainImage` from the DOM I believe, so it can't come back.  Would be better to change the `$('#mainImage').style.display` to either `inline` or `none` and vice-versa for the `#backImage`, and have them both loaded.

Removing them from the DOM each time is a little clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

A less expensive operation would be to just hide and show the main image:

```
var $main = $("#mainImage");

$("#navigation li").mouseover(function() {
  $main.hide();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $main.show();
});
```

Comment: Tried it, the problem with this is, when I `mouseout()` from one navigation item to another, for the little transition time in between, the `$main` appeared.